# Is there an online equivalent of Beer Smith?

Tags: beersmith, recipe

Simple question, does anyone know if there is a purely web based equivalent of Beer Smith / Brew Target, etc? Just looking for a decent product that I don't have to install on my desktop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple Answer:

http://beercalculus.hopville.com/recipe

Comment: Looks good! I'll leave this question open for a little and see if anyone has anything else as well.

Comment: I like it.

I'd like to build a better one...

Comment: I have been thinking of building a better one online for a while also.

Comment: I've been working on one as time permits. I'm hoping it'll be ready in a few months.

Comment: This site is no longer online

Comment: Link looks dead

Answer (score 8):

I've had very good luck with this one: http://www.brewersfriend.com/

They have a lot of different tools & calculators and a recipe builder that will save your recipes (up to five for free) and compare them against the beer style guides.

Comment: +1 for this one. Works great and development is very active.

Answer (score 2):

My co-worker and I have recently launched [brewershub.com](http://brewershub.com/) which is completely online and free.  We are looking for feedback on the site.

You can create recipes, batches for a recipe (and take notes throughout your batch), clone other recipes to change them slightly, post tutorials for other people and other features such as favorite recipes, following other brewers, etc...

We'd really love some feedback.

Thanks,
~ Tom

Answer (score 2):

BrewersHub.com just launched a recipe tool: (http://brewershub.com/recipe_builders/new).  In addition to recipe calculations, it has ingredient suggestions based on recipe style (extract/all grain) and beer style (american ipa, stout, etc), as well as descriptions.

Comment: It looks nice, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

This is little late, but I wanted to share.

Check out [brewgr.com](http://brewgr.com)

It's something a colleague and I have been working on for a few months.  We have a lot planned for it.  It's free and new features are added often.

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice work. Is it ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: It is indeed.  Is there anything else?  :P

Comment: Import BeerXML please!

Comment: It's on our hot list!  Look for it soon, and if you have more suggestions, please share them using our feature suggestion form @ http://brewgr.com/features

Comment: Now with BeerXML import!

Answer (score 1):

[BeerTools](http://www.beertools.com/) has an online version too. Registration is free.  I used to use the pay version until I started using BeerSmith.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.brew-journal.com/

One distinction from the others: it's Open-Source.

One similarity with the others: it's (very) incomplete.

(disclosure: I started this codebase)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using brewmate (www.brewmate.net)  I'm pretty new to the hobby but it was quite similar to the beersmith trial I played with and it's free.

Edit: Didn't catch the web based part of your question, but for those who want free and don't mind an install, I'll leave the suggestion up.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brewtoad.com/ is an online recipe database with them fancy web 2.0 thingys

Answer (score 0):

Try captain brew recipe builder. Here is [the link](http://www.captainbrew.com).
You build a recipe, adjust gravity, bitterness, scale, and create a brew session

Answer (score -1):

My friends and I have been working on some software that is web based and gives you a complete guide to your brew day with all mash steps depending on your equipment profile and your mash profile. We'd love to have any feedback on it and it's totally free to use.

https://www.brew-wizard.com